# How to save user input data from multiple forms (in a single template/web page) to the sqlite database in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am very new to django and on my first project.I have multiple ModelForms to be displayed in a single web page with one submit button and i want all the user input data to be stored in the db. forms.save() doesn't seem to be working if there are more than 1 forms. How do i write views for this?

```
Models.py-

from django.db import models

class PatientBasicInfo(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,) # help_text='Enter your Firstname')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,) # help_text='Enter your Lastname')
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'),)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=False)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField('DOB', null=True, blank=False)
    height = models.FloatField(null=True)
    weight = models.FloatField(null=True)
    bmi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6, null=True)

    ETHNICITY_CHOICES = (('indian', 'INDIAN'), ('asian', 'ASIAN'), ('american', 'AMERICAN'), ('others', 'OTHERS'),)

    ethnicity = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=ETHNICITY_CHOICES,default=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

class MedicalConditions(PatientBasicInfo):
    DIABETES_CHOICES = (('I', 'Type1'), ('II', 'Type2'),)
    diabetes_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=DIABETES_CHOICES, default=False)

    CONDITIONS_CHOICES = (('hBP', 'HYPERTENSION'),
        ('LBP', 'HYPOTENSION'),
        ('heart', 'HEARTDISEASE'),
        ('kidney', 'KIDNEYDISEASE'),
        ('liver', 'LIVERDISEASE'),
        ('cancer', 'CANCER'),
        ('pcod', 'PCOD'),
        ('pcos', 'PCOS'),
        ('thyroid', 'THYROID'),)
    conditions = models.BooleanField('Medical Conditions', max_length=20, choices=CONDITIONS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True, default=False)
    medications = models.TextField(help_text='Please list the medications you currently take', blank=True)

forms.py:

import datetime
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import PatientBasicInfo, MedicalConditions 
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class PatientBasicInfoForm(ModelForm):
    #required_css_class = 'required'
    def clean_date_of_birth(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']

        if data > datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError(_('Invalid date'))
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = PatientBasicInfo
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'date_of_birth', 'height', 'weight', 'ethnicity']
        widgets = {
            'gender': forms.RadioSelect, 'ethnicity': forms.Select,
        }


class MedicalConditionsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MedicalConditions
        fields = ['diabetes_type', 'conditions', 'medications']
        widgets = {
            'diabetes_type': forms.RadioSelect, 'conditions': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        }
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import PatientBasicInfo, MedicalConditions, 
from .forms import PatientBasicInfoForm, MedicalConditionsForm

def index(request):
    form1 = PatientBasicInfoForm(request.POST or None)

    if form1.is_valid():
        form1.save()

    form2 = MedicalConditionsForm(request.POST or None)

    if form2.is_valid():
        form2.save()
    context = {'form1': form1, 'form2': form2}

    return render(request, 'EDApp/Testing.html', context)


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'EDApp/home.html')
```

testing.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TestED</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form1.as_p }}
    {{ form2.as_p }}

<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your code. We need your relevant forms, views, and templates, ideally a minimal example.

Comment: @TomCarrick updated the code. I am really new to coding, so trying to figure out basics still. Thanks for your help

Comment: It's not very good to try to have all your view logic the same for both the `GET` and `POST` request. I'm not sure if this is part of the issue or not but it'd be useful if you rewrite your view to be more like this (but with the two forms): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view - note the redirect, you should always redirect after a successful POST.

Comment: Can you also show the models for `PatientBasicInfo` and `MedicalConditions`

Comment: @TomCarrick updated models. Please provide your inputs on what kind of views i could use? I want all the forms to be present in the same page with a single submit button, so not sure how redirect would help.

Comment: As in the link, you should be doing something like `if request.method == 'POST'` along with the other techniques in there. You can still do this with two forms as you're attempting to now.

Comment: it worked thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked -

```
def index(request):
    form1 = PatientBasicInfoForm()
    form2 = MedicalConditionsForm()

        if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = PatientBasicInfoForm(request.POST)
        form2 = MedicalConditionsForm(request.POST)

          if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form1.save(commit=True)
            form2.save(commit=True)

        context = {'form1': form1, 'form2': form2}
        return render(request, 'EDApp/Testing.html', context)
```